# What does "Intel Pentium 4" in system requirements mean?

Tags: cpu

I'm planing to buy a new notebook to do some animation with Adobe Flash CS 6 on it.
Adobe [claims](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/system-requirements.html#Flash%20Professional%20CS6%20system%20requirements) a `Intel® Pentium® 4 or AMD Athlon® 64 processor` is required to run the program.
I don't know much about processors - would a `Intel Pentium 987` also work?

Comment: Any processor that exceeds the capabilities of a `Pentium 4` or `AMD Athlon 64` processor will indeed work.  You should compare your processors capabilities to the [`Pentium 4`](http://ark.intel.com/products/67194/Intel-Pentium-Processor-987-2M-Cache-1_50-GHz) capabilities to determine if your processor exceeds the requirements ( it does ).  The following [Pentium 4](http://ark.intel.com/products/27423/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-1_50-GHz-256K-Cache-400-MHz-FSB) technically meets the requirements if the support article is to be believed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel Pentium 987 performs better and much more efficient in terms of power consumption and performance (IPC: Instructions Per Clock/Cycle) than any CPU from the Pentium 4 family, so it exceeds the requirements.

Pentium 987 is based on a relatively newer CPU architecture called SandyBridge, while Pentium 4 is based on a 9-year old architecture called CedarMill (Latest architecture in the Pentium 4 family). [Here](http://ark.intel.com/compare/27483,67194) is a detailed comparison between both processors.